# Why can flock(1) do inter-process lock?

Tags: flock

flock is associated with open-file-description, and open(2) creates new open-file-description. So invoking flock(1) in two separate shells will open the lock file separately and result in two open-file-descriptions. How could flock(1) know the lock status associated with each open-file-description? I am confused...
Also, does flock(1) treat path name and file descriptor differently?

**UPDATE:**

The flock I am talking about is the one under Linux.

In my understanding, the struct representing flock is system-wide unique. One or more open-file-descriptions may reference to one flock struct (like the relationship between open-file-description and i-node). Is my *'guess'* correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, `flock`, which is a wrapper around the system call `flock()`, locks on files, not file descriptors.

[The OpenBSD manual for `flock()`](http://man.openbsd.org/flock) says (my emphasis):

> `flock()` applies or removes an advisory lock *on the file* associated with
>        the file descriptor `fd`.
>
> [...]
>
> *Locks are on files, not file descriptors.*  That is, file descriptors
>        duplicated through `dup(2)` or `fork(2)` do not result in multiple instances
>        of a lock, but rather multiple references to a single lock.  If a process
>        holding a lock on a file forks and the child explicitly unlocks the file,
>        the parent will lose its lock.

`flock()` is a system call; the kernel keeps track of locks.

Comment: The questioner didn't actually say descriptors, note.  Xe said _descriptions_.  And xe quite likely took that from the _Linux_ manual page for `flock()` which specifically notes that such locks are associated with file descriptions.  Linux and the BSDs differ on this subject.

Comment: @JdeBP So they do.